# Parsing a non-escaped apostrophe in a single-quoted attribute value with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, attributes, escaping, beautifulsoup

From a webpage, I want to get all the links and title strings. I use BeautifulSoup 4 for scraping. The links on the webpage look like this:

```
<a href='http://www.example1.com' title='A small secret for better estimates #4/16/2014 8:10:30 AM'> Example 1 </a>
<a href='http://www.example2.com' title='Don't make me think #4/9/2014 4:36:07 AM'> Example 2</a>
```

The scraping solution works well:

```
#Import
import codecs
import urllib   
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Parse
url = "http://www.website-to-scrape.com"
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
htmlsrc = sock.read()
sock.close()
html = BeautifulSoup(htmlsrc)
html.__str__()
alllinks = html.find_all('a', href=True, title = True)

for tags in range(len(alllinks)-1):
        link = alllinks[tags]['href'].encode('utf-8') 
        title = alllinks[tags]['title'].encode('utf-8')
print title
```

**Problem:** BeautifulSoup does not know how to properly escape single quotes within a string, i.e. `'`.

So for example2, it will only output `Don`:

```
A small secret for better estimates #4/16/2014 8:10:30 AM
Don
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not BeautifulSoup but your HTML, which is invalid. According to the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-attribute-value), a single-quoted attribute value has the following syntax:

> The attribute name, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by a single U+003D EQUALS SIGN character, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by a single U+0027 APOSTROPHE character ('), followed by the attribute value, which, in addition to the requirements given above for attribute values, **must not contain any literal U+0027 APOSTROPHE characters (')**, and finally followed by a second single U+0027 APOSTROPHE character (').

While all of the parsers [supported](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) by BeautifulSoup will *try* to parse the invalid HTML in your question, none of them will do what you want:

```python
>>> BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example1.com" title="A small secret for better estimates #4/16/2014 8:10:30 AM"> Example 1 </a>
<a #4="" 2014="" 4:36:07="" 9="" am'="" href="http://www.example2.com" make="" me="" t="" think="" title="Don"> Example 2</a>
```

```python
>>> BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
```

```html
<html><body><a href="http://www.example1.com" title="A small secret for better estimates #4/16/2014 8:10:30 AM"> Example 1 </a>
<a am="" href="http://www.example2.com" make="" me="" t="" think="" title="Don"> Example 2</a>
</body></html>
```

```python
>>> BeautifulSoup(src, "html5lib")
```

```html
<html><head></head><body><a href="http://www.example1.com" title="A small secret for better estimates #4/16/2014 8:10:30 AM"> Example 1 </a>
<a #4="" 2014="" 4:36:07="" 9="" am'="" href="http://www.example2.com" make="" me="" t="" think="" title="Don"> Example 2</a>
</body></html>
```

Neither will any modern browser:

**Firefox**
[image: Firefox developer tools]

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome developer tools]

**IE 11**
[image: IE11 developer tools]

If you want to represent an apostrophe inside a single-quoted attribute value, you need to use the `&apos;` character entity reference:

```python
>>> BeautifulSoup("""
... <a href='http://www.example1.com' title='A small secret for better estimates #4/16/2014 8:10:30 AM'> Example 1 </a>
... <a href='http://www.example2.com' title='Don&apos;t make me think #4/9/2014 4:36:07 AM'> Example 2</a>
... """)
```

```html
<html><body><a href="http://www.example1.com" title="A small secret for better estimates #4/16/2014 8:10:30 AM"> Example 1 </a>
<a href="http://www.example2.com" title="Don't make me think #4/9/2014 4:36:07 AM"> Example 2</a>
</body></html>
```

Alternatively, you can use a double-quoted attribute value:

```python
>>> BeautifulSoup("""
... <a href='http://www.example1.com' title='A small secret for better estimates #4/16/2014 8:10:30 AM'> Example 1 </a>
... <a href='http://www.example2.com' title="Don't make me think #4/9/2014 4:36:07 AM"> Example 2</a>
... """)
```

```html
<html><body><a href="http://www.example1.com" title="A small secret for better estimates #4/16/2014 8:10:30 AM"> Example 1 </a>
<a href="http://www.example2.com" title="Don't make me think #4/9/2014 4:36:07 AM"> Example 2</a>
</body></html>
```