Parse data from local html-file using bs4?
i try to parse a local html-document using the following code -
import os, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fnHTML = os.path.join(path, "inp.html")
page = open(fnHTML)
soup = BeautifulSoup (page.read(), 'lxml')  

worker = soup.find("span")
wHeadLine = worker.text.strip()
wPara = worker.find_next("td").text.strip()
print(wHeadLine)
print(wPara)

The output look like that:
Find your favesâ€”faster
Weâ€™ve made it easier than ever to see whatâ€™s on now and continue  watching your recordings, favorite teams and more.

But the text on the html looks like that - see the picture

Why is the text not outputed with "—" and "We’ve"?

Hello @Rapid1898, it is likely due to the encoding. Please try to rewrite the loading line as the following : page = open(fnHTML, encoding="utf-8"). Also, it is cleaner to open a context manager to read from a text file. (basically rewrite this line as with open(fnHTML, encoding="utf-8") as page: and indent the rest of your code)

Did you check this link that is loosely discussing the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073837/parsing-a-non-escaped-apostrophe-in-a-single-quoted-attribute-value-with-beautif

Not reproducible without the markup.

@Lrx: thx this solved my problem
When you write this as answer i will accept it

This is caused by the windows default char encoding (cp1252). change it so it is utf-8:
Also, use a context manager to gracefully close you file stream.
import os, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fnHTML = os.path.join(path, "inp.html")
with open(fnHTML, encoding='utf-8') as file: #added encoding utf-8
    soup = BeautifulSoup (file.read(), 'lxml')  
    worker = soup.find("span")
wHeadLine = worker.text.strip()
wPara = worker.find_next("td").text.strip()
print(wHeadLine)
print(wPara)

When opening a text file, especially on windows, you WANT to force the encoding to be utf-8, for portability. This will prevent unexpected behaviors on other OS.

this is just an encoding issue while reading file, try this hope this will help
import os, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fnHTML = os.path.join(path, "inp.html")
with open(fnHTML, encoding='utf-8') as file: #added encoding utf-8
    soup = BeautifulSoup (file.read(), 'lxml')  
    worker = soup.find("span")
    wHeadLine = worker.text.strip()
    wPara = worker.find_next("td").text.strip()
    print(wHeadLine)
    print(wPara)

thanks

I have no enough reputation to comment : (, so I just dropped this in the answer section. _-
